# Play Framework: showing image via html

Tags: java, scala, playframework

So, I'm new to Play and I encounter this ***problem***:
I have a database (using jpa), let's say "Movies" and each movie has a name and an imgName. The images are stored in public-> images folder of the project.

***Question***:
How can I add the  tag in my html code in order to retrieve the image?

The following code doesn't seem to work

```
<img src='@routes.Assets.at("images/@movie.getImg()")' alt="@movie.getImg()">
```

Comment: Try to change with `'@routes.Assets.at("images/"+movie.getImg())'`

Answer (score 0):

Try to change with

```
<img src='@routes.Assets.at("images/"+ movie.getImg())' alt="@movie.getImg()">
```

All inside @ is scala code. You ask about `"images/@movie.getImg()"` - the second @ is just string - the expression  movie.getImg() is not evaluated - check generated html.

Comment: See my project: [https://github.com/ajozwik/play-seed](https://github.com/ajozwik/play-seed)

Comment: Seem like there is a problem in my model. Thank you for your time, really appreciate it.